# Freak MySql error with MAMP

Tags: macos, mamp, mysql

- I setup MAMP Pro. Before that i setup and deleted MAMP and XAMPP. I maniacally deleted all the files of the former two. Since then Apache is not running on Mamp default port 8888 and - MySql is just not running whatsoever.
- One line says "check if mysqld process isnt already running" i checked that and it is not ! 
  -Here is the error log.

> ```
> InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
> InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
> InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 35
> InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
> InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
> InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 35
> InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
> InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
> InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 35
> InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
> InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
> 130305 19:49:08  InnoDB: Unable to open the first data file
> InnoDB: Error in opening ./ibdata1
> 130305 19:49:08  InnoDB: Operating system error number 35 in a file operation.
> InnoDB: Error number 35 means 'Resource temporarily unavailable'.
> InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
> InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
> 130305 19:49:08 InnoDB: Could not open or create data files.
> 130305 19:49:08 InnoDB: If you tried to add new data files, and it failed here,
> 130305 19:49:08 InnoDB: you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back
> 130305 19:49:08 InnoDB: to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created
> 130305 19:49:08 InnoDB: in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of
> 130305 19:49:08 InnoDB: zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not
> 130305 19:49:08 InnoDB: remove old data files which contain your precious data!
> 130305 19:49:08 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
> 130305 19:49:08 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
> 130305 19:49:08 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
> 130305 19:49:08 [ERROR] Aborting
>
> 130305 19:49:08 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
>
> 130305 19:49:08 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
> ```

Comment: Here is the solution that solved this messy problem.

[Aral Balken's blog #1931](http://aralbalkan.com/1931/)

Answer (score 61):

Just search for "Activity Monitor" application on MAC and search for any task called mysql and end it.
Then restart MAMP it will work. Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Even though I kill it, it just recreates it self

Answer (score 8):

End any `mysql` or `mysqld` task (or other) in your **Activity Monitor** application.

Answer (score 6):

If you cannot kill them with **Activity Monitor**,
in **Terminal** do
`$ ps aux | grep mysqld`
The 2nd column is the process id, and you can stop it with (if it is 1234)
`$ kill 1234`

Answer (score 0):

I was solved this problem by kill mysqld process:

To kill all mysqld process **on Linux** :

```
# killall mysqld mysqld_safe
```

Wait for 10 seconds atleast so that it shut down cleanly.
Now, run this command to check whether still there are some mysqld process remained or not ?

```
# ps aux | grep mysqld
```

If you still able to see more than run this command :

```
killall -9 mysqld mysqld_safe
```

This will kill all mysqld processes.

Answer (score 0):

Just restart your pc , that solved it for me